# USB bootable device is not showing

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have DELL inspiron 7560 which has pre installed with windows. I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu. I have created a booatable device. But on startup it is not showing USB drive to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

What tool/utility did you use to create the bootable USB?

If you did use Rufus to create your USB, after setting up the USB and clicking "START", select **"Write in DD Image Mode"** instead of "Write in ISO Image Mode". 
I have found that writing in ISO Image Mode tends to make bootable Linux USB's to not appear or work properly.

Computers nowadays use UEFI by default, so make sure that your bootable USB is formatted as **GPT**. Otherwise if you create a bootable USB with MBR instead of GPT, it may not be visible.

Make sure that you are going into either the F12 boot menu in the BIOS, or set the boot order priority in the BIOS, or else you won't be able to boot from the USB drive.